# Find position of exact match in a string

Tags: python, nlp

I am looking for exact match of words in string. I wrote the code as follows to find the position of each **exact** match of elements in list in the string but it does search if a word is not exact match.
can anyone help me?

in the following example the exact match is *from*.

```
text = "Greeting from here"
lis = ["greet", "from","re"]
import re
pos = []
for i in lis:
    pos.append(text.find(i))

current output: [-1, 9, 1]

Expected output: [9]
```

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: I want position of FROM only, just exact match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *re.search()* as follows:

```
import re

text = "Greeting from here"
lis = ["greet", "from", "re"]

pos = []

for i in lis:
    if m := re.search(rf'\b{i}\b', text):
        pos.append(m.span()[0])

print(pos)
```

**Output:**

```
[9]
```

Comment: what is 1 in [9, 1] ? I only need [9], so only position of exact match

Comment: Answer edited now that the requirement has been clarified

Comment: what is this line is doing m.span()[0]?

Comment: what does this means? rf'\b{i}\b'

Comment: I refer you to Python documentation for both the *re* module and general string handling (f-strings in particular)